# groovy: change setter properties call order

Tags: groovy

In my groovy class, I have 3 properties below:

```
class Story{
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Object collections;

    String dateformat;    

    @JsonUnwrapped
    Object  custom;    

    public String getDateformat(){
        println "getDateformat - ${dateformat}";
        return this.dateformat;
    }
    public void setDateformat(String str){
        this.dateformat = str; 
        println "setDateformat - ${dateformat}";
    }

    public void setCollections(Object obj)
    {
        println "setCollections";
    }
    public void setCustom(Object obj){
        println "setCustom: ${this.dateformat}";
    }
}
```

On class instanciation, the setters are automatically called is this order:

```
setCustom: null
setCollections
setDateformat - yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
getDateformat - yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
```

The fields can not be renamed. I would like dateformat property to be available in setCustom setter method. Is there any way I could achieve that without creating a second custom constructor?

Comment: How is your object created?

Answer (score 2):

To my surprise, yes!

And it's super simple. I excluded the JSON annotations since they are irrelevant, but here's an example:

```
class Story{
    Object collections
    String dateformat
    Object  custom

    public String getDateformat(){
        println "getDateformat - ${dateformat}";
        return this.dateformat;
    }
    public void setDateformat(String str){
        this.dateformat = str; 
        println "setDateformat - ${dateformat}";
    }

    public void setCollections(Object obj)
    {
        println "setCollections";
    }
    public void setCustom(Object obj){
        println "setCustom: ${this.dateformat}";
    }
}

def s = new Story(collections: new Object(), dateformat: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z', custom: new Object())
```

The output looks like this:

```
setCollections
setDateformat - yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
setCustom: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
```

### How does it work?

The trick is to call the `Map-`based constructor with the properties defined in the proper order.

The default `Map`-based constructor provided by Groovy is actually handled by the runtime. More specifically, [MetaClassImpl](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/78b6cc54af85988829ecd6120b69f65e0d9a8ade/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.java#L1714). It first creates an instance with the no-argument constructor, and then sets each of the properties in the `Map`. The important thing here is how the properties are set:

```
for (Iterator iter = map.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
    String key = entry.getKey().toString();

    Object value = entry.getValue();
    setProperty(bean, key, value);
}
```

As you can see, it iterates through the keys in the `Map` and applies each one. When using the constructor syntax in my example, you're declaring a Groovy `Map` literal, which ends up being an instance of [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). `LinkedHashMap` preserves the order in which the keys are defined, allowing you to control the order in which the properties are set.

### Should you even do this?

Having said all of that, having such an unintuitive dependency on the order in which the properties are set will make the `Story` class quite fragile. Instead, you can add a new method, lets call it `validate()`, which will take into account the interdependencies of the properties and ensure everything is good to go before you *use* the instance.

```
class Story{
    Object collections
    String dateformat
    Object custom

    boolean validate() {
        /*
         * Do whatever the hell you want with
         * dateformat and custom.
         * Return whether it's all good or not.
         * Or, throw an Exception.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right about attempting to put an order on setters. I need to rethink how I'm going to use the dateformat property

Comment: Honestly, this question does not make sense, and your answer just try to explain something which is not defined in this question ;-) the short answer could be : "groovy doesn't call the setter when an object is created", and "property are not ordered". the map constructor is just a syntaxic sugar on the call to the setters. only the code creating an instance can call the setter in the order it wants.

Comment: So @jérémie-b, if the question *does not make sense* to you, how would you know whether any given answer answers the question or not?